# Calculating the Downside Deviation of an Array of Returns

Tags: python, finance, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to calculate the downside deviation of an array of returns using the code below:

```
def downside_deviation(arr):
    downside_returns = 0
    arr.loc[arr < 0, 'downside_returns'] = arr
    down_stdev = downside_returns**2
    arraysize = downside_returns.count()
    down_stdev = downside_returns.sum()/arraysize
    down_stdev = np.sqrt(down_stdev)*np.sqrt(12)
    return down_stdev
```

But I keep encountering the and AttributeError as below:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'loc'

I'm wondering if anyone could me on this error as nothing I have tried has worked so far.

Thanks a million for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `arr` variable should a Pandas DataFrame, but you passed the `float` object for the `arr` variable. So, it raises the `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'loc'`.

Additionally, I see this `arr.loc[arr < 0, 'downside_returns'] = arr` might raise the next error if your `arr` is actually a Pandas DataFrame. To use it correctly, you may need to read more in its documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - for example, `df.loc[df['shield'] > 6, ['max_speed']]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a float into the function, but it expects it to be a type that has a .loc attribute.

Python is "duck typed". You can pass anything you want as the argument, but when it comes time to use the members, if they are not present you will get an error like this.